# Highcharts is formating x axis text values as dates

Tags: highcharts

For some reason, Highcharts is formatting my text categories as dates.

**Background Info**
I am getting my data from a Google Spreadsheet. The labels should say Grade 12, Grade 11, etc. I know I can overwrite the xAxis labels with the categories function, but I want I sustainable solution so that my end users can change the labels as they wish.

- [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ecupaio/pen/mJEgwx)

```js
$(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
      defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
      backgroundColor: '#fff', 
      shadow: false
    }
  });
  $('#ms-highschool').highcharts({
      data: {
         googleSpreadsheetKey: '1Nx8zcIi0ULxytLmra0A9N11-llzJCDVH2-7SbK_k5-U',
         startColumn: 0,
         endColumn: 1,
         startRow: 0,
         googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: 5
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Charter School Makret Share for High School Grades, SY 2014-15'
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 40,
        tickInterval: 10,
        title: {
          text: 'PCS Share'
        } 
      },
      xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
        }
      }  
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
  <script>
  
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ms-highschool"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: can you post the input data?

Comment: Running the code as posted produces the proper categorized result for me...

Comment: But in your spreadsheet there is no information that about GRADE, only I see a column Categories with values: 9,10,11,12.

Comment: Sorry about that. I switched it to test some other solutions. Declaring the type solved the issue in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify type of x axis explicitly to have the problem solved.

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    type: "category"
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help. Also, is there an alternative guide to Highcharts documentation? Everything I know about highcharts has been derived from stackoverflow posts and codepens.

Comment: You can always check http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts. Most of paragraphs will lead you to jsFiddle so that's very easy to see concept in action